# Constructing a first order linear differential equation that have a specific behaviour

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm currently stuck with a problem where I'm supposed to find all solutions that are asymptotic to the line $y=3-t$ when $t\to\infty$. This is the demand, from here I'm supposed to create a first order linear differential equation. Can someone help me get started with this problem? Unsure of how to start....

Asymptotic would mean that for example $x(t)=y(t)-1/t$ would satisfy the given demand, not sure how to go further with this although.

A first order linear differential equation means I should have some sort of connection between my function and the derivative of the function, I cant make that connection....

It's my first time using this forum so I've probably made every mistake you can make, hopefully my question is still relevant...

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is it to construct a first order linear differential equation which has a solution (or all solutions?) asymptotic as $t \to \infty$ to $y=3-t$?

Comment: yes, exactly, should've clarified that better

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, gonna try to work with the help I've gotten and see if I get somewhere, at least I have a start now

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recipe, which I think is the only recipe for a first order linear differential equation such that *all* solutions are asymptotic to a given function. (There are other ways to get *some* solution asymptotic to a given function.)

1. Find a first order linear differential operator $L$ such that all solutions to $Ly=0$ go to zero.
2. Identify a function $g(t)$ such that $y=3-t$ is a solution to $Ly=g$.
3. A solution to your problem is then the equation $Ly=g$.

#1 should be easy. #2 is also easy once you think about it the right way.

This works because the general solution to $Ly=g$ is of the form $y_p+y_h$ where $y_p$ is any solution to $Ly=g$ and $y_h$ is the solution to $Ly=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Try with $y(t)=e^{-t}+3-t$ which solves the linear differential equation $$y'(t)+y(t)=at+b$$ with some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.
Notice that $\lim_{t\to +\infty}[y(t)-(3-t)]=\lim_{t\to +\infty}e^{-t}=0$.

Since $y_o(t)=e^{-t}$ is a solution of the homogeneous problem, it suffices to check when $3-t$ is a solution:
$$(3-t)'+(3-t)=-1+3-t=-t+2=at+b\quad \Rightarrow\quad a=-1, b=2.$$

Answer (score 0):

There is an infinte number functions with that asymptotic: any function $$f(t)=-t+3+g(t)$$ has the asymptotic $-t+3$ as long as $g(t)$ is of the leading order $O(t^{-1})$ for $t\rightarrow \infty$. A few examples:
$$t^{-1}-t+3,$$
$$t^{-2}-t+3,$$
$$e^{-t}-t+3.$$
So finding "all solutions" with the asymptote $-t+3$ is impossible because there are an infinite amount of them with very different functional forms.

But now to your differential equation: if you have one solution you can just differentiate it to get a very simple differential equation. For example for $f(t)= t^{-1}-t+3$:
$$\frac d {dt}f(t)=-1 - 1/t^2,$$
which is a first order differential equation of $f$. To get the proper asymptote you would also need a right boundary condition: for example $f(1)=3$.

You could construct more complicated differential equations (higer order, nonlinear,...) or use a different functions.